# My columns are too small inside my panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see from my image I have a panel with 2 columns inside. I also need these columns to have input fields for a form. The problem is I can't get the input field width to be the same size as the column. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Test Heading
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Column1Row1">Column1Row1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column1Row1">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Column2Row1">Column2Row1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column2Row1">
                                    </div> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="Column1Row1">Column1Row1</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column1Row1">
    </div> 
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Column1Row1">Column1Row1</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column1Row1">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included `row` class and then inside the `row` you need to extend the label and input in total to 12 columns. So, the label occupies 3 columns and input field occupies 9 columns.

**Example:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     Test Heading
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Column1Row1">Column1Row1</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column1Row1">
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="row form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="Column2Row1">Column2Row1</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
         <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" name="" value="" id="Column2Row1">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply but I'm afraid I need 2 columns of col-md-6. Can you help?

Comment: Yes, its two columns. Run the code snippet above and click on `Full Page` to see it in full page.